# How to use Macbook m1 as simulator with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can run Flutter app on M1 device from Xcode natively. It means I'm using MacBook as a device, like a simulator.

How can I list this device from flutter run?

[image]

Comment: are you using stable version of flutter sdk?

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh yes, stable and latest

Comment: right now mac os development not in stable in flutter  so i don't think you can build app in mac os desktop.

Answer (score 0):

That's at the moment of this writing not possible with Flutter's built in device selector. What you can do is to enable desktop support for your application using [this tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop) and select your macOS as a target after that and run like normal.